# Meta tag `IE=EmulateIE9` results in unexpected document type

Tags: html, internet-explorer, meta, http-equiv

I am working on a site that is using the following:

- Doctype: `<!DOCTYPE html>`
- Meta tag: `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" value="IE=EmulateIE9">`

When I run the site in IE > IE9, I am expecting the site to render in IE9 standards mode.  This is not happening.

This is the behavior I am seeing:

- Internet Explorer 11 -> Document mode 11
- Internet Explorer 11 in compat mode -> Document mode 7
- Internet Explorer 10 -> Document mode 10
- Internet Explorer 10 in compat mode -> Document mode 7
- Internet Explorer 8 -> Document mode 8 (this probably makes sense...)

Why is this happening?  I have a reasonable doctype so it should render in IE9 standards.  The MSDN page on the topic says that if I use `IE=EmulateIE9` then the doctype will be choosen as:

> IE9 mode (if a valid  declaration is present)
>
> Quirks mode (otherwise)

*Just to be clear, I am not asking how to make the document render in IE9 standards mode.  I know that I can just use `IE=9` instead of `IE=EmulateIE9`.  My question is: **Why isn't the document rendering in IE9 standards?***

Comment: Is there an online resource available that you are testing against?

Comment: @JonathanSampson - Sorry, there is not.

Answer (score 0):

Please check the Internet Explorer Standards Support Documentation Overview:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff405771(v=vs.85).aspx

Inside it states:

> 2.1.2.5 Compatibility View
>
> Compatibility View settings can also impact the document mode
>   selection:
>
> - If a webpage is retrieved from a website in the Local intranet zone (see "About URL Security Zones" at [MSDN-SECZONES]), **IE7 mode is
>     used**.

or

> - If the webpage is retrieved from a site in a domain on the    Compatibility View list (and the list is active), IE7 mode is used
>     (see "Understanding the Compatibility View List" at
>     [MSDN-UnderstandingCompViewList]).

So most likely, this matches your case